# IOS Safari has Block pop-ups feature . is there any functionality same for UIwebview or WK webview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

How to disable Block pop-ups functionality for UIWebview or Wkwebview in Objective C (programically to disable block popup )?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Include some code you have already tried writing or other things you might have tried.

Comment: i tried to load one url in ios  web view . but that url will work only if the popups are enabled . so in webview its not working . how to enable the popup in webview